# Как сохранить состояние чекбокса в localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Есть код который добавляет значение для чекбокса в localstorage

```
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1zaal1'));
if (checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("checkbox1zaal1").checked = true;
} 

function save(){
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input');
    localStorage.setItem('checkbox1zaal1', checkbox.checked);
}

$('.check').click(
function() {
save();
}
)
```

Проблема в том что код работает только для одной айдишника, соответсвенно один ключ для одного чекбокса.
Возможно ли как то преобразовать код для того что бы значение для каждого чекаута хранилось отдельно в одном ключе?

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkTok/8zdyps5h/23/

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не получилось?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
в локал записывается только один чекбокс
второй уже не работает  так как один ключ используется
хотелось бы узнать как можно записывать все чекбоксы в локал

Answer (score 2):

В примере ниже я использовал идентификаторы элементов, в качестве ключей для `localStorage`

https://jsfiddle.net/strangerintheq/bt7ndo5g/

смотрите fiddle, т.к. в сниппете localStorage отключен

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".check").forEach(el => {
  el.onchange = () => localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked);
  el.checked = localStorage.getItem(el.id) === "true";
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class='check' id="checkbox1zaal1">
<input type="checkbox" class='check' id="checkbox1zaal2">
```